# How to rename a CUPS printer?

Tags: linux, command-line, printing, cups, yast

I do lot of printing in command line through lpr command, for which I need conveniently short destination names like lp1, lp2 etc. In past I could name the printers, but in opensuse 13.2, yast automatically selects a very long CUPS printer names with no option to change it. This is inconveninet for getting printing done in command line. Even if I change manually in cups.conf, it gets overwritten (perhaps by systemd?) with name chosen automatically by yast. The web interface of CUPS behave similarly. Is there a convenient way to rename CUPS printer name?

Answer (score 4):

1. *Stop CUPS Service*.
   For openSUSE using `systemd` there are three services to stop (`cups.path`, `cups.service`, and `cups.socket`).
2. *Edit* `/etc/cups/printers.conf` and replace the old-name text with the new one. (appears only once).
3. *Rename drivers*: In `etc/cups/ppd` there are "drivers" named like the printer, so if you change the printer name, also rename the driver files.
4. *Start the services*.

Answer (score 0):

There is a yast printer module that allows for manual configuration.

From https://en.opensuse.org/YaST_Printer :

> The main purpose of the YaST printer module is the manual configuration. "Manual" means that you have full control what is set up. There are no silently working hidden automatisms which result whatever the automatism "thinks" is best for you.